# Jquery Mobile Filterable Select : Not working like Demo. Why?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filter

I am trying to reproduce the functionality seen here :
http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/examples/filterable/filter-inside-selectmenu.php

Basically, I just want to be able to put a listview style search filter on select control with many options in jquery mobile.

I am using the current versions of JQuery and JQM, which are 1.10.1 and 1.3.2 respectively.

I have created a fiddle to show what is happening : 
http://jsfiddle.net/LY6EJ/

Now, when I use the current version of JQuery Mobile, I get an error on line 28 below, Javascript Runtime Error : Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
 // Instantiate a filterable widget on the newly created listview and
 // indicate that the generated input is to be used for the filtering.
 listview.filterable({ input: input });
```

Now, if I instead use the copy of jquery mobile that they have on the demo page, which resides at : http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/js, the crazy thing works, it just breaks all of my other jquery mobile related functionality.

The script they are using does not have a Version identifier.  I am hoping someone here knows javascript well enough to figure out what they did, or what I didn't do that will make sense.  Maybe they included another plugin to create widgets or something similar in the modified script?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the demo was part of the Alpha test.  Evidently JQM has separate demo portals for each version released.  The functionality present in the Demo will not be released until 1.4x